# How to stop cmd .bat from closing up -- java jar application

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd

I have this batch file

```
java -jar evac.jar
```

which runs a java console application. It works, but when it's done it auto-closes, thus proving pointless to me.

How would I stop it from closing after execution so that I could analyze my data

Comment: add PAUSE at the end of batch file and you should be through

Comment: You could pipe your results to a file and look at the file afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could append

```
pause
```

to your batch file which will wait for a keystroke before closing.

Comment: Yes, your script should look like this: java -jar evac.jar<newline> pause<newline>